# Error While Installing magento2 In searchConfig.pg line81: could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. Unknown 401 error from 0 pensearch null

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2, opensearch

I'm installing Magento 2 for the first time following this tutorial https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-install-magento-2-using-composer. XAMPP is installed (with Apache and MySQL running), the database is setup on PHPMyAdmin, but when I try to run php bin/magento setup:install (step 23 in the tutorial) I get the error
In searchConfig.pg line81: could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. Unknown 401 error from 0 pensearch null

```
{
  "name" : "HOME",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "5lWbyUHRQgyHeByx7CgSQw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.10.3",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "zip",
    "build_hash" : "c63272efed16b5a1c25f3ce500715b7fddf9a9fb",
    "build_date" : "2023-10-05T10:15:55.152563867Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But When running this command

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://magento2.magento.com" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2" --db-user="magento2" --db-password="magento2" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="Admin@123456" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --search-engine=elasticsearch8 --elasticsearch-host="es1:9200" --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

I get the error In searchConfig.pg line81: could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. Unknown 401 error from 0 pensearch null

How can I fix this error?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP 401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) generically represents `username:password` issues on your OpenSearch/Elasticsearch login. (Elasticsearch would next-step error [HTTP 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) if it recognized the authentication credentials but refused to authorize them.)

*Side comment*: You've tagged `elasticsearch` but are asking about `opensearch` where [the former is on version](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch) `8.10.4` (in your code output) and the [latter is on version](https://opensearch.org/) `2.11.x`. Since these products features+roadmaps have [diverged since Elasticsearch 7.11 which became Opensearch 1.0](https://www.elastic.co/pricing/faq/licensing), I'd suggest you clarify which of the two you're using.

I'd suggest starting investigating by verifying that your Elasticsearch/OpenSearch database

1. is running on `https://localhost:9200` (where port `9200` is default for Elasticsearch *or* is your database setup against generic ports HTTPS `443` or HTTP `80` or another custom port set in your database config.)
2. can be authenticated via the `username:password` pairing in your command above with the port confirmed in (1) e.g.

   ```
   curl -k -u "magento2:magento2" https://localhost:9200
   ```

   E.g. you might be intending to authenticate with a different `username:password` pairing in which case you could update this portion of your code snippet: `--db-user="magento2" --db-password="magento2"` after confirming the new pairing is working.
3. And finally, once you've confirmed `username:password` (2) should function, you might return to if the Magento setup command requires you listing the expected port. The success of testing this depends on your exact 2.x version of Magento, e.g. [StackExchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181213/magento-2-integration-test-db-port) resolving in [github/magento2#4275](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/4275) on v2.2

Comment: Thank you. But still I'm facing same issue. And I 'm installed elasticsearch for search engine but Y it shows opensearch I did't get that idea.